# What are the polynomial quotients $R/x$ and $R/(R/x)$ for $R = (\mathbb{R}[x]/x^n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, polynomial-rings

Define the polynomial ring quotient $R = \mathbb{R}[x]/x^n$. Is my understanding correct that

$$ R/x \cong \mathbb{R} $$

and accordingly, as scalars divide all polynomials,

$$R/(R/x) \cong \{1\}$$

If not, how would you characterize $R/x$ and $R/(R/x)$?

Answer (score 3):

I'd prefer to use the common parenthesized notation for ideals, i.e., $R=\Bbb R[x]/(x^n)$ etc.

Strictly speaking, $x\notin R$ and hence $(x)$ is nor n ideal of $R$. Instead of $x$, we should use the image of $x$ (and element of $\Bbb R[x]$) under the canonical projection to $R$, aka. the residue class of $x$, or $x+(x^n)$.
With these caveats, **yes**, we have 
$$ R/(x+(x^n))\cong \Bbb R$$
per the obvious homomorphism.

**However,** there is no good way to view $R/(x+(x^n))$ as an ideal of $R$ (even on the level of mere sets, viewing the elements of $R/(x+(x^n))$ as the constant polynomials in $R$ or $\Bbb R[x]$ is not natural), hence we cannot speak of a quotient $R/(R/(x+(x^n)))$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand your concerns regarding viewing R/(x+x^n) as an ideal of R. Still I have an exercise sheet with a question asking to compute the quotient, and so I'd be interested what would be a good way to fudge this? See, https://imgur.com/a/vgOrtUx